Pandas, find difference between two columns, each having different datatype values
consider following input data



prod
col1
col2




One
hi
hello


One
18.0
19.52


One
2024-02-12 00:00:00
2024-03-07 00:00:00


two
2024-02-12 00:00:00
2024-02-11 00:00:00


two
in-transit
in-stock



want to find difference between col1 and col2, since there is difference in datatype in each row, I am facing difficulty to apply pandas functions. using SQL knowledge tried this code but didn't work
logic:

if str then difference = "not same"
if datetime then difference = (col2-col1).days
else difference = col2 - col1

df["difference"] = np.where( df['col2'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str)), "not same", 
                                df["col2"].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, datetime)), (df['col2'] - df['col1']).dt.days, 
                                df['old_value'] - df['new_value'])



** Not getting expected output, datetime is still in timedelta
Expected output:



prod
col1
col2
difference




One
hi
hello
not same


One
18.0
19.52
1.52


One
2024-02-12 00:00:00
2024-03-07 00:00:00
25


two
2024-02-12 00:00:00
2024-02-11 00:00:00
1


two
in-transit
in-stock
not same



Any other approach please suggest

Please provide a [mre] of the input as code (e.g. output of df.to_dict('list'))

I think the most reliable would be to convert the two columns to_numeric/to_datetime and perform the differences/comparisons in the desired order:
import numpy as np

cols = ['col1', 'col2']

tmp_num = df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
tmp_date = df[cols].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')

df['difference'] = (
 tmp_num[cols[1]].sub(tmp_num[cols[0]]).abs()
 .fillna(tmp_date[cols[1]].sub(tmp_date[cols[0]]).dt.days.abs())
 .fillna(pd.Series(np.where(df[cols[0]].ne(df[cols[1]]), 'not same', np.nan),
                   index=df.index))
)

Variant:
c1, c2  = 'col1', 'col2'

df['difference'] = (
 pd.to_numeric(df[c1], errors='coerce')
   .sub(pd.to_numeric(df[c2], errors='coerce'))
   .fillna(pd.to_datetime(df[c1], errors='coerce')
             .sub(pd.to_datetime(df[c2], errors='coerce'))
             .dt.days
          )
   .abs()
   .fillna(df[c1].ne(df[c2]).map({True: 'not same'}))
)

Output:
  prod                 col1                 col2 difference
0  One                   hi                hello   not same
1  One                 18.0                19.52       1.52
2  One  2024-02-12 00:00:00  2024-03-07 00:00:00       24.0
3  two  2024-02-12 00:00:00  2024-02-11 00:00:00        1.0
4  two           in-transit             in-stock   not same


def calculate_difference(row):
    val1, val2 = row['col1'], row['col2']
    if isinstance(val1, (int, float)) and isinstance(val2, (int, float)):
        return abs(val1 - val2)
    elif isinstance(val1, pd.Timestamp) and isinstance(val2, pd.Timestamp):
        return abs((val1 - val2).days)
    elif isinstance(val1, str) and isinstance(val2, str):
        return "not same" if val1 != val2 else "same"
    else:
        return "not comparable"


df['difference'] = df.apply(calculate_difference, axis=1)

